# Is it possible to setup Travis-CI for a public GitHub repo I'm only collaborator in?

Tags: travis-ci

I'm a collaborator with https://github.com/martinh/libconfuse/, so I can
push and tag stuff. Most references on the Interwebs is for this URL, so
it would be convenient to be able to set up Travis-CI (and more) for this
repo, not my own fork.  Is this possible?  (The original maintainer can no
longer spare the time.)

Considering my options, maybe the simplest way to go about this would be to
maintain everything in my own fork? (https://github.com/troglobit/libconfuse)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're required to have Github admin access for setting up the hooks, so yes use the simple way and fork it or see that the owner gives you the required access.

Alternatively he might be convinced to transfer ownership but github does not do redirects for repo's (they do for hosted sites), which would defeat the purpose (https://help.github.com/articles/transferring-a-repository/)